# Exclude office.interop if MS office not installed

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, office-interop

My problem is my program crashes at run when it is opened by a computer that does not have office installed.

I am writing a program where that will be run by multiple users on different computers.   Some users computers will have MS office installed, others will not.  It is a multi-form program and for ease of reference can be thought of like an ERP type software.

I have included Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook in the program references.  Certain sub forms within my application use both excel and outlook functionality, however many do not.

I would like both users who have and do not have office installed to be able to run the program.  Perhaps if they do not have office installed they receive an error stating that they do not if they were to click a button that would normally export an excel spreadsheet of data.

Is there any way to achieve this?

I would like to avoid third party libraries, having to install office on all computers as it will not be needed on those workstations, I would also like to manage one program and not have two separate programs to manage which would share forms and functionality.

Comment: Self-contain (on their own assembly) all methods calling those two references, and check for the DLLs before calling those methods.

Comment: if you are using the assembly in your project you can either set the `copy local property = true` or you can manually copy the .dll to the bin folder so that it gets copied when ever you deploy..

Answer (score 2):

With the restrictions mentioned - no third party libraries, no office on some user machines, and no 2 versions of the program //  Read the Excel files as datasource into the program and deal with the data that way.  For where you mentioned "export an Excel Spreadsheet" you can use ODF/ODS.

Answer (score 2):

I setup a new form and tested out what specifically in my application was causing my program to crash.  I found out that including the office references does not cause a problem.  Also adding `using Microrosoft.Office.Interop.Excel;` does not cause a problem.

However I was calling a Class in my main program that that created Excel application's, workbooks and worksheets, despite not actually using those items on program load.  An example of a local variable in the class that likely caused the problem was `private Excel.Application XLApp = new Excel.Application();`.

I will probably use a solution like @Jcl suggested before allowing a user to run anything that may crash the program on them.